# User name not shown in 'Created and Modified by' in list item

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I created an app with one list using Visual Studio 2013 and deployed it as a Sharepoint-hosted app to a Sharepoint 2013 Server on premise/farm.

The only field in the list was the default Title filed. When I add an item to the list, the details on created and modified by are as shown in Figure 1. Notice that it said "..  on behalf of  ..". The user who added the item was not recorded in the details.

However, if I created an app using the OOTB custom list template and add an item to the list, the details on created and modified by are as shown in Figure 2. The user who added the item was reflected in the details.

Why is there a different and how to make the app I created using Visual Studio to behave the same as the one created from the template?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using any event receiver or modifying content in any way from VS?

Comment: I did not use any event receiver or modifying content. The app and list I created used all the default setting and not custom code was added.

Comment: I also did not set any permission under app manifest in VS

Comment: If the created by is displayed as in Figure 1, it is still possible to filter list view by using the option 'user can read only their own items'?

Comment: How are you adding item to the list ? For both scenarios are you using same method to add item?

Comment: In both scenario, items were added to the list using the same method. It was via the new item link in the list view (i.e. .../Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx).

Comment: In Figure 1, the user name 'SP Developer" is the account I used to deploy the app via Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry for asking but I am not sure I got it right. You are comparing a SharePoint app created from Visual Studio that defines a custom list in it - which will then result in an app site with a list with a standard, out of the box, custom list (which is called an "app" too, but it is still an element on the "main" site)? If that is the case, I think that that is the main difference: apps live in their own isolated space, and that should be reason for the different message. I will try and check if I can find a way to have them behave the same.

Comment: Hi SPArchaeologist. You described it correctly. My aim is to capture the user who created the item in the list in my Sharepoint-hosted app and then use the name to filter the list view. For example, user can read only their own items. What happened to my app as shown in Figure 1 was no matter who created the item, the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy always bear the name of the developer who deploy the app to the site from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When you save as a new document, have you selected “replace existing file”?

If you do not select the option, it will create another file in the same library. You could select the option to check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Anyway, there are two separate apps. One created using Visual Studio and the other from the OOTB custom list template. Thanks.